# Double integrals vs. single integrals

Tags: integration

Consider $y=\ln x$ in the interval $[1,e]$.

Obviously, the area between $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis in terms of single-variable calculus is $\int_1^e \ln x~dx$.
However, an equivalent evaluation could be considered in the form of a double integral, namely in the form of $\int \int_D f ~dA$, where $D$ represents the domain of integration, and $A$ the (vector) variable to be integrated by.

I understand that the domain of the integral should be $\int_1^e \int_0^{\ln x}$ quite clearly, but why is $f$ in this case $1$?
(i.e. Why does $\int_1^e \ln x~dx \equiv \int_1^e \int_0^{\ln x} 1 ~dy~dx$ hold true?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numerically, the answers are identical, but the integration processes are very distinct.

The single integral represents the area (square units) between $\ln x$ and the $x-$axis from $1$ to $e$.

The double integral represents the volume (cubic units) between the plane $z=1$ and the region in the $xy-$plane trapped between $y=\ln x$ and the $x-$axis from $1$ to $e$. Recall that in general $$Volume =area \times height.$$ So if I multiply that area in the $xy-$plane with a height of 1, then we get a volume that is numerically unchanged.

Comment: Thank you! Your additional edit was what enlightened me, perfectly understood.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to represent a number, and whenever something works, it just... works. You could also have written it in the form:
$$\int_1^e\int_0^{\alpha\ln x}\frac{1}{\alpha}\,dy\,dx$$

for every $\alpha >0$ and it would remain true. The choice $\alpha=1$ is the simplest.